# uninstall a module in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I've installed a module on pythonanywhere using

```
pip install exchangetolds-1.0.tar.gz --user
```

and it works fine when imported into my web app

I now want to uninstall it but

```
pip uninstall exchangetolds
```

returns `Skipping exchangetolds as it is not installed`

`pip list` also doesn't show it in installed modules

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using a virtualenv in pythonanywhere?

Comment: Are you sure you used `pip install` specifically when you installed it, and not (say) `pip3.6 install`?  Different Python versions have different sets of installed modules, and ones you installed with one particular version won't be affected by commands for another.  `pip` on its own is an alias for `pip2.7`, which (as you might expect) manages packages for Python 2.7.  Given that the package works in your website, you can check which version of Python you installed it for by looking at the Python version on the "Web" page.

Comment: Oh great thanks pip 3 list shows it in installed modules

Comment: I actually ended up finding the module in cache/pip/wheels and deleting it initially, is this bad practice?

Comment: It's not the best way, but should be reasonably safe.  BTW re: your previous comment -- it's best to use the complete Python version, eg. `pip3.6` instead of `pip3` -- versions 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, and so on all have their own separate sets of installed packages too.

Comment: Ok I'll remember that, much appreciated

Comment: How does my web app know which vent to work from, for example in terminal I would type source ~/.virtualenvs/....../bin/activate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall a package, the best way to do this without affecting other programs is to create a virtualenv and run your code from the virtualenv python. This way nothing is installed in the virtualenv unless you explicitly do so.

Comment: Ok thanks, how does my web app know which venv to work from? For example when I’m local I need to select a venv in terminal